# Connect various quotes and other characters to print out in a text file

Tags: vba, text

I have the following string I need to print to a text file.  I've tried mixing char map entities in it but can't come up with the combination.

```
FOR %%f IN ("%~dp0*.dxf") DO "C:\Program Files\Widget builder 2020\widget.exe" /i "%%f" /s "%~dp0cleanup.scr" /l en-US
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Mike

Comment: Try : "FOR %%f IN (""%~dp0*.dxf"") DO ""C:\Program Files\Widget builder 2020\widget.exe"" /i "%%f"" /s ""%~dp0cleanup.scr"" /l en-US"

Comment: Awesome!!  Thanks!  I've been beating my head all day trying to figure that out!!

Comment: Another question:  I want to get the "cleanup.scr" location from a text box.   when I put ScrAddress in place of ""%~dp0cleanup.scr"" it fails.

Thanks in advance